# Avoid number truncation in pandas rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, truncate

I have a dataframe column which had more than 14 digits, which may sometimes run upto 20 digits.

Issue i'm facing is, once i have read the csv file using pd.read_csv() rows having long numeric values get truncated / rounded off to next number
eg `Original row value = 10173555000199`, after reading csv file to pandas, value changed to = `10173600000000`. Not sure why this is happening.

Is there a way to avoid this while reading data through csv file?

Comment: that's not normal, but might be due to the data type, try setting `dtype` to np.int64 for example for your column and see what happens in the   `pd.read_csv()` function. Also can you share with us a portion of your data ?

Comment: @mrCopiCat Issue is numbers are changing the minute I read the data, at a point where it does not matter even if i convert the column. Also the I tried the details shared for a similar question. It does not solve the issue

Comment: what i meant by setting the time is setting it inside the pd.read_csv() function like : `df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, dtype={'values': np.int64})` can you try like that ?

Comment: @mrCopiCat  some of the numbers ```Numbers
10173555000199
10277092000105
10325444000150```

Comment: @mrCopiCat I tried the above code suggested. output remains truncated numbers

Comment: @mrCopiCat Can you please unblock the question. solution is not there in the link shared above

Comment: did you, by any chance open the file with excel ? I know it seems weird as a qst but excel have a huuge tendency to ruining csv data

Comment: Yes, It is an excel file which I converted to csv and read the data to python